# Как собрать JSON с использованием библиотеки SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift

Вот такой JSON ждёт от меня сервер

```
$_POST['json_function'] = ‘{
"params": {
    "auth_token": "32342fgh5u6jwjwu25uargat35y",
    "contacts": [{
        "name": "Cheesy",
        "phone": ["555-478-7672", "555-478-7673"]
    }, {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "phone": ["(555) 564-8583", "####"]
    }]
},
    "func": "getContact"
```

}
’;

проблема в создании этой конструкции

```
 "contacts": [{
    "name": "Cheesy",
    "phone": ["555-478-7672", "555-478-7673"]
}, {
    "name": "Daniel",
    "phone": ["(555) 564-8583", "####"]
}]
```

Есть массив имён  и массивы телефонов

```
 Contacts.arrContacts

 Contacts.idPhoneNumber
```

Вот так вот создаю JSON

```
     let jsonGetContacts : JSON = [
            "func" : "getContact",
            "params" : [
                "auth_token" : "\(userToken)",
                "contacts" : ??????
            ]
        ]
```

Как собрать это дело, нужна помощь ребят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `SwiftyJSON` можете просто подставлять массив и он уже преобразует к нужному виду. Это если просто. В данном же случае предварительно необходимо создать массив объектов со структурой

```
"name": "Daniel",
"phone": ["(555) 564-8583", "####"]
```

и затем подставить вместо `??????` в

```
"contacts" : ??????
```

Ваши 2 массива должны быть одинаковыми по размеру и элементы в массиве имен соответствовать элементам в массиве номеров(и элемент это массив номеров). Может все же лучше в массив `Dictionary`? Тогда получится как-то так:

```
var contacts = [[String: AnyObject]]()
for i in 0..<Contacts.arrContacts.count {
    contacts.append(["name": Contacts.arrContacts[i], "phone": Contacts.idPhoneNumber[i]])
}

let jsonGetContacts : JSON = [
    "func" : "getContact",
    "params" : [
        "auth_token" : "\(userToken)",
        "contacts" : contacts
    ]
]
```

Comment: спасибо, всё работает